# Empty body when sending success email with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have this fragment in my Jenkinsfile

```
post {
   success {
     mail to: 'user@email.com',
     subject: "The email subject",
     body: "Something very interesting",
     charset: 'UTF-8',
     mimeType: 'text/plain'
   }
}
```

The problem is that I receive the emails but the body of the emails is empty and no error is being shown in the Jenkins console.

I have tried changing the double quotes in the body section to single quotes (body: 'Something very interesting') even setting the body this way without success:

`body: '''Something very interesting'''`

Comment: Are you trying to use the Email Extension plug-in?

Comment: I tried but I don´t have it installed. I need to ask to the admin to install it. Thanks you for answering

Comment: Ok then you might need to have it, you'll just have to change `mail` to `emailext`, else, you're code is good